# Redirect to Chrome - Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, google-chrome, redirect

Supose the default browser of the user of my application is IE. 
I want my application to redirect to a website using google chrome by an click event

For example: clicking a button and then a new chrome tab/window pops with my own website)

I already tried using the webbrowser tool inside Visual Basic, however the website layout just goes all messy, so i guess this is the best way to do it.

PS: 
I'm using Visual Basic Studio 2010

Comment: The default browser is per machine not per application. You should not force a different browser onto someone who (for some reason) is using IE by default

Comment: and what if your user doesn't have google chrome?

Comment: well, my website is optimised for chrome, but yes, the user may not have google chrome so how can i redirect to the default browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't stated whether this is WinForms or ASP.NET but I will assume you are using WinForms

Your question was misleading because it mentioned [redirect which is a method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) in ASP.NET web applications.

However, to answer the question:- you can open a web page using the default browser by simply doing this:

```
Process.Start("http://www.bbc.co.uk/f1")
```

If you want to open a specific browser you could try searching for the exe file.

The Google Chrome exe on my machine is in `AppData\Local` but this could be different on different machines.

The following code finds the chrome exe and loads a page on my machine:

```
Dim files As ReadOnlyCollection(Of String)
Dim startFolder = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "Google\Chrome")
files = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(startFolder, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, "chrome.exe")
If files.Count > 0 Then
    'We found the exe so open a web page
    Process.Start(files(0), "http://www.bbc.co.uk/f1")
Else
    'Chrome not found so start the default browser
    Process.Start("http://www.bbc.co.uk/f1")
End If
```

But if the path changes this will fail.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative to the above would be to use the registry.

Dim chromePath As String = _
   Microsoft.Win32.Registry.GetValue( _
   "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\chrome.exe", _
   "Path", "Key does not exist")

if chromePath is set to nothing then not found.

Many ways to skin a cat, as they say !

Answer (score 1):

If you know the location of the path to Chrome you might be able to do something like this (Internet Explorer used for example as don't have Chrome installed)

Process.Start("C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe", "http://www.google.com")

Comment: Thanks! I guess i can use a try catch to see if chrome is installed, if not just start the IE.